# Dragging JFrame from JToolbar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am currently attempting to move a JFrame (the same way you would by dragging the window's title bar) when the mouse is being held down over a JToolbar. The JToolbar is inside several layers of JPanels nested in the JFrame. How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: There seems to be some confusion about what I'm aiming for here. I still want the titlebar to be draggable, but I just want to extend that functionality to the JToolbar as well (while keeping JToolbar *not* floatable - locked in place in the frame). See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: *"I am currently attempting to move a JFrame .. when the mouse is being held down over a JToolbar."*  That is not the path of least surprise!  I would expect that dragging a tool bar would remove it from the frame, while dragging any other component within the frame would have no effect unless D'n'D' was invoked or it had some other specific drag behavior (like a `JScrollBar`).  Why do you want to inflict this GUI upon your unsuspecting users?

Comment: The JToolbar I'm using is set as the same background color as the title bar, and it looks like one large piece. The toolbar is also *not* floatable, so there is no context there to tell the user to try and drag it. It's simply a matter of increasing the draggable surface area.

A screenshot would explain it best: http://i.imgur.com/XOnfK.png
Disregard the ugly icons though haha... they're temporary.

Comment: Is your app. for *nix only?  That would look quite odd on Windows XP/7 with Aero enabled.

Comment: It looks pretty great on XP/7 (tested on both), haven't tried it with *nix or osx. It's using SeaGlass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Component Mover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) should work. See the last example. Instead of a titleBar you have a toolBar.

Comment: I'm looking to make both the toolBar and the titlebar draggable. Check out my edit.

Comment: @Meff, doesn't change my answer.

Comment: I looked into it briefly and I was having trouble getting it to work, but I'll put a little more elbow grease into it and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Don't understand the problem. Its a single line of code. You create the ComponentMover class with the "frame" and the "toolBar" as parameters.

Comment: Worked beautifully. I appreciate the help very much. Have an awesome day!

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the most elegant solution, but...

You could create a class that extends a JToolbar and that implements a MouseMotionListener. When the user clicks on it, you would use setBounds() on the JFrame and give it a new location relative to how much the user moves the mouse within the JToolbar.